# Variable passed to ng-incude in angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs

I tried different ways to achieve this, with no luck. I also read few post on same subjet, I don't know why I can't get this to work.

I want to use ng-include to display template content in a component. Since it's a reusable component, I'm passing the template id via bindings.

```
 angular.module('app')
  .component('detailPanel', {
    templateUrl: "components/_detailPanel.html",
    bindings: {
      templateId: '@'
    }
  }
);
```

The component _detailPanel.html:

```
<div>
  {{$ctrl.templateId}}
  <ng-include src="$ctrl.templateId"> </ng-include>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="actionDetail.html">
  THIS IS THE DETAIL
</script>
```

I'm passing the templateId to the component. It prints fines in the div using {{ templateId }} and this indicates the correct id is passed, but nothing is shown from ng-include. The only way I'm able to get the template to be rendered is to pass the string 'actionDetail.html' to the ng-include's src. However I'm looking to pass a variable because I want something reusable..

This example contains the ng-template directly in the component, but I intend of course to put it oustide, this was only a test.

Any thoughts would help... thanks

Comment: Finally I was able to achieve my goal using a callback function defined in the parent and called from this component. The function returned the string 'actionDetail.html' and the ng-include's src was calling it. It's not beautifull, but it's the only way I was able to make it work...